# Convenient "write-back" with helper temporary objects

Tags: c++

I have a lot of code, which uses value references for purposes of returning multiple results from function calls, like:

```
T deserialize(const uint8_t* source, size_t bytesAvailable, size_t& bytesRead) const;
```

This works well, but usually requires a lot of boilerplate code (declaring a designated variable and processing the result), so I figured, that for common operations - like accumulating or discarding the value - I can make use of "helper" temporaries, which will do all the work without polluting the code, e.g. (*the following code was updated a bit since the original question*):

```
template <typename T> struct WritebackValue {
    class Base {
        protected:
            T _value;
        public:
            template <typename... Args> Base(Args&&... args) : _value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { }
            operator T& () {
                return _value;
            };
    };
    class Discard : public Base {
        using Base::Base;
    };
    template <typename TSink = T> class Accumulate : public Base {
        private:
            TSink& _sink;
        public:
            template <typename... Args> Accumulate(TSink& sink, Args&&... args) : Base(std::forward<Args>(args)...), _sink(sink) { }
            ~Accumulate() {
                _sink += Base::_value;
            }
    };
};
```

Which allow super-convenient function calls:

```
size_t bytesRead;
auto a = Serializer<A>().deserialize(source, bytesAvailable, WritebackValue<size_t>::Accumulate<>(bytesRead, 0));
auto b = Serializer<B>().deserialize(source + bytesRead, bytesAvailable - bytesRead, WritebackValue<size_t>::Accumulate<>(bytesRead, 0));
auto c = Serializer<C>().deserialize(source + bytesRead, bytesAvailable - bytesRead, WritebackValue<size_t>::Discard());
```

**Question is:** is the above approach safe? E.g., does standard **guarantee** that temporary will be destroyed by the time the next line of code is executed? Will the temporary lifetime be guaranteed to be as long as function call duration in case of implicit cast to underlying value? This seems to be working fine in clang, but I would prefer an exact wording from the standard to be sure I'm safe with other compilers like MSVC.

Comment: Yes, your code will work as expected. But you need to type long statements. Hm, and if they are easy to read? I doubt it. For me it sounds like a so called XY problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem. What you really want to do, and you even mentioned that, you want to return multiple values from a function. And this is nowadays done with structered bindings. Very simple. And serializing / deserializing is usually done by overwriting the extractor and inserter in a class. But I guess that there is a reason for your approach, so I cannot really judge.

Comment: Yes, this question is purely about code safety from the standard's standpoint - not about "the best/correct approach" (I've edited the question a bit make it clearer). But, anyway, thanks for letting me know about structured bindings - they seem like a convenient and powerful feature. Unfortunately, I'm currently stuck with C++14, since switching to C++17 breaks compilation of my code for some reason - but I will surely keep them in mind.

Comment: Don’t quite have time to write a full answer, but http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4 and https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#5.6. Yes, it’s perfectly safe.

Comment: Great, thanks - these seems to be answering all my questions. Please feel free to post a full answer and I will be glad to accept it.